# Big O Notation: Justifying f(n) ∈ O(n^4)?

Tags: java, time-complexity, big-o

This is a java exercise book problem. I have looked for a method to solve with no success.

Let `f(n) = 100n^4+ 5000n+ 3. Is f(n)∈ O(n^4)?` If yes, then justify your answer by supplying the appropriate positive constants `c` and `n_0`.

I believe the answer is no, but I need guidance on how to approach the problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `f(n)` definitely should have `O(n^4)` performance, but I lack the formal math to answer your exact question.

Comment: It's not about performance. n is in O(n^4). 3 is also in O(n^4). The whole thing is in O(n^4).

Comment: The approach is to go back to the mathematical definitions of Big O notation.   Probably the definitions given in your text book.  Then do what question asks by providing the values.  It is some simple algebra ... (And the answer is yes ... actually.)

Comment: It may be an excercise from a Java book, but I don't think the Java tag is appropriate. It's just an excercise on algorithms and Big O notation.

Answer (score 2):

you can prove it in this manner,

100n^4 +5000n +3 < 5000(n^4 +n+1) for all n>1 ...(1)

5000(n^4 +n+1) < 5000(n^4 + n^4 + n^4) for all n>1 ... (2)

Which implies that

100n^4 +5000n +3 < 15000(n^4) for all n>1

So, it is proved that 100n^4 +5000n +3 is O(n^4)

Answer (score 0):

```
Let f(n) = 100n^4+ 5000n+ 3
```

For simply, we will remove all constant

```
Let f(n) = n^4+ n
```

we will use a few arithmetic to evaluate:

```
Let f(n) = n^4+ n = n(n^3+1)
```

We will continue to remove the constant

```
Let f(n) = n(n^3+1) = n*n^3 = n^4
```

So the final

```
f(n)∈ O(n^4)
```

Please notify me if i misunderstand something, i am still learning Algorithm.